# LDAP user groups

Tags: spring-security, ldap, openldap, saml-2.0, spring-saml

How can I get users group list (as attribute) that user belongs too. I want to use LDAP server as SAML auth source and then I want to map LDAP attributes to SAML attributes and use them in spring-saml authentication for J2EE application group based role management. What I did at this moment it is LDAP->SAML->Spring-security (SAML module) authentication. But I can't get groups after login because LDAP didn't return them together with other information (cn, email, gidNumber and etc)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using the OpenLDAP `memberOf` overlay you have to do a search for groups with the DN of the user as a value of the group membership attribute, which might be `uniqueMember` or `roleOccupant,` depending on how you have set up your LDAP server.

If you're using the `memberOf` overlay, just request the value of the `memberOf` attribute when you lookup the user.